# Python problems setting x-axis dataframe in matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, matplotlib

My current graph is displaying the full range of data correctly.

I am having problems setting the x-axis on my graph though. My code is the following:

```
prices['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(prices['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
prices['Timestamp'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(prices['Timestamp'])
prices.index = pd.to_datetime(prices['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


prices['Close'].plot()

plt.set_xlim([datetime.date(2017, 12, 17), datetime.date(2017, 12, 18)])


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives me the error

> Blockquote AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_xlim'

I really want my graph to show the timestamp to be from 2017-12-17 22:00:00 to latest time.

Sample of the data looks like:

```
print(prices['Close']

2017-12-18 07:13:00    3.030000e-06
2017-12-18 07:14:00    3.020000e-06
2017-12-18 07:15:00    3.030000e-06
2017-12-18 07:16:00    3.040000e-06
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
#set column to datetime
prices['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(prices['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#set index from column
prices = prices.set_index('Timestamp')
#plot column, return matplotlib AxesSubplot object
ax = prices['Close'].plot()
#set xlim
ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2017, 12, 17), datetime.date(2017, 12, 18)])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I still get the full range of dates. also I only want from 2017-12-17 22:00:00 to latest time (not just dates?).

Comment: Hard question, what about `ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2017, 12, 17, 22, 0, 0), df.index.max()])` ?